# ¿Cómo mostrar los datos de una consulta SQL en vertical en vez de horizontal?

Tags: sql

Ya tengo mi consulta hecha, solo que en vez de mostrarme los datos en horizontal, me gustaría que los muestre vertical. Lo estoy haciendo en *NetBeans* en una aplicación *Java Web*.

Código:

```
<div class="container">
  <thead>
    <center><table class="table" border="1">
      <tr class="success">
      <%
      consulta conexion = new consulta (
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","pasaportes","oppasaportes"
      );
      String consulta = "SELECT * FROM delegaciones WHERE id_delegacion ='1'";
      ResultSet rs = conexion.ejeSelect(consulta);
      ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
      int col= rsmd.getColumnCount();
      for(int k=1;k<=col;k++){
      %>
        <td><h4> <%= rsmd.getColumnName(k) %></h4></td>
      <%
      }
      %>
      </tr>
      <%
      while(rs.next()){
            %>
      <tr class="info"> 
        <td><h4><%= rs.getString(1) %></h4> </td>      
        <td><h4><%= rs.getString(2) %></h4> </td>
        <td><h4><%= rs.getString(3) %></h4> </td>
        <td><h4><%= rs.getString(4) %></h4> </td>
        <td><h4><%= rs.getString(5) %></h4> </td>
        <td><h4><%= rs.getString(6) %></h4> </td>
        <td><h4><%= rs.getString(7) %></h4> </td>
      </tr>   
      <%
      }
      %>
    </table></center>
  </thead>
</div>
```

Comment: Puedes trabajar tu consulta de SQL con un PIVOT. Puedes revisar esta liga. https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya hice el intento como muestra el ejemplo pero no me funciono. seguiré buscando alguna otra forma, se agradece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirando tu query, estás obteniendo una sola fila de resultado, y la quieres desplegar como columna.

En ese caso puedes hacer:

```
<%
while(rs.next()){
  for(int k=1;k<=col;k++){
%>
<tr class="info">
   <td><h4> <%= rsmd.getColumnName(k) %></h4></td> 
   <td><h4><%= rs.getString(k) %></h4> </td>
</tr>
<%
  }
}
%>
```

Para obtener la tabla en la forma nombre columna - valor

Comment: Muchas Gracias  a todos por sus aportaciones, me ayudo mucho!!!